# Where does html5 libgdx app save Preferences files?

Tags: java, html, libgdx

As I read here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Preferences files will be saved to `~/.prefs/` (I'm on linux).

When I run desktop app, it works fine, and preferences file is saved to the right place. But with html5, it doesn't save that file! I'm sure it was saved somewhere, because the game still can read it (it contains scores).

My code is really simple, just:

```
    Preferences score = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Highscore");
    score.putInteger("score", _points);
    score.flush();
```

I built the game by running

```
./gradlew html:dist
```

and run it on localhost created by python

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then go to `http://localhost:8000` on Firefox.

Anyone could help? Thanks for reading, have a nice day.

Comment: Uh, that prefs file is probably what is created when you use Java. But when deployed as "html5" the game will become Javascript through GWT, it won't have anything to do with Java anymore. The settings are probably saved in a different way, such as a cookie or client local storage.

Answer (score 1):

I found my .prefs in my libgdx html game by running the game in Chrome, right clicking and choosing Inspect Element, clicking on the Resources tab, expanding the Local Storage tab, and examining the entry https://myAppName. This is where the .prefs are kept...

Comment: Note: If using a later version of Chrome, the name of the "Resources" tab in Developer Tools has changed to "Application".